# Why does this throw up an error?

Tags: applescript

```
tell application "VoodooPad"
    tell document 1
        repeat with thisPage from 1 to number of items in pages
            set theName to display name of page thisPage
            set creationDate to created of page thisPage
            set theText to text of page thisPage
            tell application "Evernote"
                create note with text theText title theName notebook "VoodooPad Imported Notes" tags "imported_from_VoodooPad" created creationDate
            end tell
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

This produces the following error:

```
error "VoodooPad got an error: every item of every page of document 1 doesn’t understand the count message." number -1708 from every item of every page of document 1
```

Any Idea on how to get the script to run?

Comment: I just downloaded the demo version. It must be something special with that "pages". "pages of document 1" does not work. May be you can ask the VP Support!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
set allPages to pages as list // now you have items in a list
repeat with thisPage from 1 to number of items in allPages
...
```